# Qt: Hidden widget being returned for nextInFocusChain()

Tags: qt, focus, qwidget

I have two checkboxes (QCheckbox), the first of which I sometimes hide. After calling hide() I then want to retrieve the nextInFocusChain() for the parent widget. This returns the first checkbox, regardless of whether it's hidden or not. Am I doing something wrong? I would have thought that a hidden widget isn't part of the focus chain, so it shouldn't be returned.

```
if (shouldHideFirstCheckbox) {
    firstCheckbox.hide();
}
QCheckBox* nextWidget = dynamic_cast<QCheckBox*>(nextInFocusChain());
// nextWidget is always firstCheckbox, regardless of whether it's hidden
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: it's by design.

If you look at the implementation of `QWidget::setTabOrder()`, you'll see that widget's visibility isn't taken into account: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.cpp.html#6969